# Populating Select list with PHP and SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I am calling from my SQL server a list for the options and outputting into an array.. see query:

**SQL**

```
$location = "SELECT location_id, location_name, location_postcode, location_buildingname
             FROM   dbo.system_locations";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $location );
```

**PHP**

```
<select class="form-control" name="location">
   <?php while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)){ ?>
     <option>
        <?php echo $row['location_name']?>
     </option>
   <?php } ?>
</select>
```

This works great, however I want the option which is selected within the database to be the selected option..

There is one factor, the select list can be added to by visiting settings section and adding new location otherwise I would use the ternary operator method.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $location);` instead?

Comment: Thanks for the edit @HawasKaPujaari apologies I narrowed down the code

Comment: So, what in the database determines which one should be selected?

Comment: against the staff record, I have a column which contains location_id

Comment: Can you explain more in detail why you cant use the **ternary operator** method ??

Comment: Can you expand your question slightly to show how the code you have included should have access to this staff record?

Comment: Sorry guys.. 

I have two tables, one contains locations, one contains members of staff..

Against the staff record I have saved the location id.. I want to output all the locations on the staff record but have the choosen one selected.. then if user wants to update they can select from dropdown and assign new location.. 

Within settings of my system user has ability of adding new locations, so the new locations must appear in select list.

Comment: Please edit your original question to add new information or more clearly explain what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<select class="form-control" name="location">
   <?php while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)){ ?>
   <option <?php ($row['selected'] == 1){echo 'selected';}?>>
      <?php echo $row['location_name']?>
   </option>
   <?php }?>
</select>
```

Comment: this will not work according to OP: _"There is one factor, the select list can be added to by visiting settings section and adding new location otherwise I would use the ternary operator method."_

Comment: actually i cant't understand what you want?

Comment: Sorry guys.. 

I have two tables, one contains locations, one contains members of staff..

Against the staff record I have saved the location id.. I want to output all the locations on the staff record but have the choosen one selected.. then if user wants to update they can select from dropdown and assign new location.. 

Within settings of my system user has ability of adding new locations, so the new locations must appear in select list.

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.